# How can I call a specific success callback based on the result of .ajaxSuccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Apologies if this has already been asked in some way shape or form but I couldn't quite find exactly what I wanted to achieve so here goes.

In this particular case, any AJAX call made to this specific servies always returns two properties like so :

```
// Success Response
{
  error : null,
  success : [
      { ... some data here ... },
      { ... some data here ... }
  ]
}

// Error Response
{
  error : [
      { ... some errors here ... },
      { ... some errors here ... }
  ],
  success : null
}

// Global Handler

$.ajaxSuccess( function (resp) {
  if(resp.error !== null) {
    /*
      Call a global function for handling API errors
      Prevent execution of AJAX callback
    */
    apiHelper.doErrorValidation(resp.error);

  } else {
    // Execute specific success callback of the request function
  }
});

// Specific Handler

$.ajax(function () {
  url : 'theUrl',
  success : function (resp) {
    specificModule.specificFunction(resp.data);
  }
});
```

As stated in the code block comments, how can I ensure that .ajaxSuccess() stops the AJAX call if resp.error !== null, but execute the success callback in the specific ajax call otherwise?

Comment: `console.log(resp.error)` before if loop

Comment: That is not really an elaborate answer, nor is it really helpful. Why would that do what I want to achieve?